# A question about Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I just don't know how to calculate the the fourier transform of $1/(1+x^2)$.Can you help me guys? Thx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the duality property of the Fourier transform:

---

**Theorem:** Let $\hat{f}(w) = $$\mathcal{F}[f(t)]$, then the following duality property holds:

$$\mathcal{F} \, \big [\hat{f}(t) \big ] = 2 \pi f(-w).$$

---

So, look at your table and see this convenient identity:

$$\mathcal{F} \, \Big [\frac{1}{2a}e^{-a|t|} \Big ] = \frac{1}{a^2 + w^2}.$$

Now apply the duality property:

$$\mathcal{F} \, \Big [  \frac{1}{a^2 + t^2} \Big ] = \frac{\pi}{a} e^{-a|w|}$$

Then, the answer to your question is:

$$\mathcal{F} \, \Big [  \frac{1}{1 + t^2} \Big ] = \pi e^{-|w|}.$$

Comment: I got , THANK YOU VERY MUCH